# How to start bridge0 on macOS?

Tags: macos

The virtual network `bridge0` on my Mac is inactive:

```
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
```

How do I enable it?

---

My Macbook Pro configuration:

```
macOS Big Sur
version 11.5.1

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
```

I want to start up the bridge0, because I am studying minikube, which create a docker vm and the minikube bridge attached to bridge0 (from a tutorial, check below snapshot)

[image]

my requirement is communicate to minikube cluster IP from my macos.

en1 and en2 config:

```
$ ifconfig en1 
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c0 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
$ ifconfig en2
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:13:08:b0:ec:c1 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
```

Comment: Why do you want to activate your ethernet connection? Are you having trouble connecting to the Internet over wifi? Is there an ethernet cable connected to your computer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you add the output of `ifconfig en1` and `ifconfig en2` to your question? I have the impression that `bridge0` appears as inactive because both members (`en1` and `en2`) are inactive.

Comment: I have updated my post, please check it.

Answer (score 1):

The bridgeO is the Thunderbolt bridge that bridge together the various Thunderbolt 3 adapters in your mac (in my MacBook Pro 2018, there's 4 of them, all members of bridge0).

Ethernet is a buit-in feature of thunderbolt 3.

To bring this bridge active, you need to bring a thunderbolt Ethernet interface up, so connect a device that use this feature.

Note: the standard Apple Ethernet adapter is really a USB-C to Ethernet adapter, not thunderbolt, and doesn't bring up the thunderbolt interface. (it creates a separate interface)

If you really want to bring the bridge up (why?), you can probably add another interface to the bridge (like the usb-c to Ethernet adapter) and connect this interface. You can give it a shot using the `brctl` command.

Comment: I have updated my post, please check it.